# Split user names, arrange them in alphabetical order and create all possible words with them in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame which consists of user names say -`df`

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['Harry Potter'],['Ron weasley'],['Hermione Granger'],['Rubeus Hagrid'],['Dobby'],['Draco Malfoy']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['names'])
df

    names
0   Harry Potter
1   Ron weasley
2   Hermione Granger
3   Rubeus Hagrid
4   Dobby
5   Draco Malfoy
```

what I want - **1)** split the word   **2)** arrange them in alphabetical order  **3)** make all possible words with them and should be alphabetically arranged(considering the first letter of the word)

so it should be something like -

```
     names           alphabets  words
0   Harry Potter    aehoprrrty  Ate, Hat, Heart, Party, Pot, Prey, Toy
1   Ron weasley     aeelnorswy  Lean, New, Rose, Worse, Won
```

Please help me to get the desired result in fewer lines if possible

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution, but really not easy parse all possible english words with good performance - one idea is use `set`s, but then possible assign multiple letters:

```
import nltk

english_vocab = {w.lower(): 
                 set(w.lower()) for w in nltk.corpus.words.words() if len(w) > 2}
    
f1 = lambda x: ''.join(sorted(y.lower() for y in x if y != ' '))
df['alphabets'] = df['names'].apply(f1)


f2 = lambda x: sorted([k for k, v in english_vocab.items() if v <= x])
df['new'] = df['alphabets'].apply(set).apply(f2)
print (df)
              names        alphabets  \
0      Harry Potter      aehoprrrtty   
1       Ron weasley       aeelnorswy   
2  Hermione Granger  aeeegghimnnorrr   
3     Rubeus Hagrid     abdeghirrsuu   
4             Dobby            bbdoy   
5      Draco Malfoy      aacdflmoory   

                                                 new  
0  [aer, aerate, aerator, aero, aeropathy, aerope...  
1  [aal, aaron, aeaean, aenean, aeon, aer, aero, ...  
2  [aam, aani, aaron, aeaean, aegean, aegerian, a...  
3  [aaru, aba, ababdeh, ababua, abaiser, abaissed...  
4  [bob, bobby, bobo, bod, bodo, body, boo, boob,...  
5  [aal, aam, acalycal, acamar, acara, acarol, ac...
```

Comment: Sir thanks for your answer, generated words are really funny.. but yes ,  needs to be more effective.

Comment: @L_for_LeaRniNg - I tjhink you need some research in pure python for this task. really complicated.

Comment: Sure sir, would you mind if I ask you to upvote my question if you feel this question has a good base.